# how to add github credentials in jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

[image: Screenshot]

The Add button is disabled and the dropdown shows 'none'. How do I add my github credentials in this section.

Comment: I tried and it is not enabled even after entering the repo link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try with the credentials tab as below:

[image: Credentials tab]

[image: Credentials tab for adding new creds]

Then it should show up in here:

[image: Add credentials for git repo]